# Call method on class with NHibernate Criteria

Tags: nhibernate

Say i have a object like this

```
public class Student{
    public IList<Coursework> Courseworks{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}

    public bool HasCompletedCoursework(int courseyear, string moduleName)
    {
         return Courseworks.Any(x => x.Courseyear == courseyear && x.ModuleName == moduleName && IsComplete);
    }
}

public class Coursework{
    public int Courseyear{get;set;}
    public string ModuleName{get;set;}
    public bool IsComplete {get; set;}
}
```

is it possible to call the HasCompletedCoursework method on the Student class when you use ICriteria to query the database.

Cheers 
Colin G

Comment: minor refactoring: IsComplete == true -> IsComplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ICriteria is  designed to build Sql queries. If you can change this method to some sql criteria, then yes, otherwise - no.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the criteria api, but instead using the linq 2 nh api, extracting a predicate in the form of `Func<bool, Student>` that could be used both by the `Student` class and the repository (or whoever queries) in the form `Expression<Func<bool, Student>>` in order for the DB to do the work.